# fetching data from tableview cell?

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data

God evening :-D

i have a a tableview,(using core data)  i pub the cell with a "Todo" like: "5 mile Run" and i set the detailed text  to @"points value @", X   were x is a number set by a slider, and the same time u set name for the Todo.

i have put in a button in the cell, and called it add, and i want to be able to add that number in the detailed text  to a "totalPoints" attribute in my core data model.

i can make a fetchRequest for the entity,but how do i make sure that i get that number,   and how do i use simple math when the "pointValue" is stored in NSNumber object.

Update :

fixed it :-D

if u add a button to your cell, u can get that indexPath like  this :

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {


if (![sender isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]]) return;  

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];
if (![cell isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]) return;  

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell: cell];

// do something with indexPath.row and/or indexPath.section.
```

this fixed my app, and it´s now in beta testing :-P

Thanks for your help

Skov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample code, there are a couple issues. First, when you are getting the values a, b and e you can just do this:

```
NSNumber *a = toDo.pointsValue;
```

(assuming that toDo.pointsValue is an NSNumber).

Secondly, in your if statement you are comparing the values of the pointers, not the values in the objects that the pointers point to.

This code should have the result you want (I assume you initialize toDo in some way) :

```
ToDo *toDo;
CGFloat x = [toDo.pointsValue floatValue] + [toDo.totalPoint floatValue];
//Note: it is better to use CGFloat rather than plain float
CGFloat y = [toDo.goodiesPoints floatValue];
if (x >= y)
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(winView) 
               withObject:nil 
               afterDelay:0.5];
}
```

I am not sure exactly what you mean when you say "how do i make sure that i get that number".  What number is "that number"?

Comment: "that number" is the detail text i set for etch cell, so lets say that the detail text for 5 mile run is  10 and my toDo.goodiesPoints is set to 30 in the settings view, the plane is that u need to put add 3 times in that cell to open the winView, the code u set works fine but, i seem to be missing something, cuse it dos not  add 10 point to totalPoint, so it only works if goodiesPoints is les then the pointValue set in the cell.